# Blazor WebAssembly, don't use MIME Type application/octet-stream

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WebAssembly creates .dll Files, which it downloads to a Client Computer and runs the website with. You can also make it create .bin files instead of .dll files when publishing, which is what we do. Both .dll and .bin are of MIME Type "application/octet-stream"

We see a surge of forward proxies and firewalls that block the MIME Type "application/octet-stream", which makes Blazor WebAssembly not work anymore. Customers of ours that block this MIME Type, can't access the Application anymore

Is there any way, to serve Blazor WebAssembly files with a different MIME Type, that hopefully isn't blocked by most Firewalls and forward proxies?

**Update:**

We changed all the applications that were affected by this from Blazor WebAssembly to Blazor Server, while still using .NET 6. We tried .NET 8 preview, but it was still too buggy.

Comment: Have you tried changing the mime type to something innocuous, like text/plain or application/json?

Comment: We did try to change the mime type, but to applicaiton/wasm. Just broke the application completely. Trying your suggestions now

Comment: If someone is blocking your payload because of security concerns, I would suggest discussing those concerns with them rather than trying to find a way to defeat their firewall. If I was your customer and found that you had changed your product deployment to avoid my firewall,  I would not be your customer any longer.

Comment: @MisterMagoo I agree with you, however - we are not an IT company, our customers are not IT customers. They need the application in their daily work life. And since this is more of an architectural problem in Blazor WebAssembly Framework itself, and not our application, I think we are allowed to search for workarounds. The application itself is not malicious and does nothing malicious so I think while your concern is valid, getting to have it up and running again is more important, for us and our customers.

Comment: Maybe you could package it as a hybrid app and have them install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Blazor 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-5/#blazor) the standard packaging will be webcil.

I'm not sure if that overcomes your mediatype problems but it is probably the best that can be done.

It's not spelled out anywhere that I can find but I assume it's going to use application/wasm.

When a firewall blocks that you're probably at the end of the road.

Comment: That is true and I already read about this. Blazor finally uses .wasm instead of .dll which as you said is application/wasm. However, I can't wait for that unfortunately, because .NET 8 Release is in November, and the problem is currently very urgent - I would need to bypass the blocking of application/octet-stream preferably yesterday :).

Comment: The document that H H linked to states using ```<WasmEnableWebcil>true</WasmEnableWebcil>``` in your project .csproj file works right now with .Net 8. Just tested on a Blazor WASM app of mine and instead of .dll files in _framework there are .wasm files.

Answer (score 0):

.Net 8?
Apparently outputing .wasm instead of .dll is the new default in .Net 8 Blazor WASM so no flags are needed to output .wasm files instead of dlls. I guess the question is, can you use .Net 8? It would seem to solve your problem by using the mimetype application/wasm.

.Net 6 7 and 8
Alternatively you could follow the instructions [here on Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-8.0#compression) and use the compressed dlls which are Gzip (.gz) or Brotli (.br) compressed. Gzip's mimetype is application/gzip. The compression method works in .Net 6 and 7 also.